# LOOP into cursor until each IF ELSE true in oracle

Tags: oracle, if-statement, stored-procedures, cursor

I have written a `cursor` where I want to LOOP each and every column until it becomes true. So if all the IF statement matches to true then I want to insert the data into `VALID` table or at last I want to insert the incorrect data into the `INVALID` TABLE.

Below is the cursor. Kindly let me know whether my step is accurate or Do I need to make any changes in that.

```html
create or replace procedure fiber_transm_valid_data as 
begin
  for cur_r in (select rj_span_id, 
                       rj_maintenance_zone_name,
                       rj_maintenance_zone_code                
                from app_fttx.transmedia@sat               
               )
  loop               
    if cur_r.rj_span_id > '0' then       
  elsif cur_r.rj_maintenance_zone_name = 'aa' then
   elsif  cur_r.rj_maintenance_zone_code = 'A123' then
    INSERT INTO VALID TABLE 
    (span_id, maintenance_zone_name,rj_maintenance_zone_code)
       values (cur_r.rj_span_id, cur_r.rj_maintenance_zone_name, cur_r.rj_maintenance_zone_code);
    
    ELSE
   INSERT INTO INVALID TABLE 
    (span_id, maintenance_zone_name,rj_maintenance_zone_code)
       values (cur_r.rj_span_id, cur_r.rj_maintenance_zone_name, cur_r.rj_maintenance_zone_code);
  end loop;  
end fiber_transm_valid_data;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not quite like that; `IF` is wrong. Have a look at this.

```
create or replace procedure fiber_transm_valid_data as 
  l_state_name table_of_states.rj_state_name%type;
begin
  for cur_r in (select rj_span_id, 
                       rj_maintenance_zone_name,
                       rj_maintenance_zone_code,
                       rj_state_name
                from app_fttx.transmedia@sat               
               )
  loop         
    select max(rj_state_name) 
      into l_state_name
      from table_of_states
      where rj_state_name = cur_r.rj_state_name
        and rownum = 1;

    if     cur_r.rj_span_id > '0' 
       and cur_r.rj_maintenance_zone_name = 'aa' 
       and cur_r.rj_maintenance_zone_code = 'A123'
       and l_state_name = 1       
    then       
       INSERT INTO VALID_TABLE 
         (span_id, maintenance_zone_name,rj_maintenance_zone_code)
          values 
         (cur_r.rj_span_id, cur_r.rj_maintenance_zone_name, cur_r.rj_maintenance_zone_code);
    else
        INSERT INTO INVALID_TABLE 
          (span_id, maintenance_zone_name,rj_maintenance_zone_code)
           values 
          (cur_r.rj_span_id, cur_r.rj_maintenance_zone_name, cur_r.rj_maintenance_zone_code);
    end if;       
  end loop;  
end fiber_transm_valid_data;
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212238/discussion-on-answer-by-littlefoot-loop-into-cursor-until-each-if-else-true-in-o).